# How to display image using <img src=" "> from system directory in JSP

Tags: html, mysql, image, jsp

I am trying to fetch image which is stored in My local system directory, I stored image path in MySQl database and the path of image is

```
 H:\IVS-FEB 2016\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\IVS\uploads\share1.png
```

I'm trying to fetch this path using

```
<img src="<%String pathup =rs2.getString("pathup");out.print(pathup);%>" width="200" height="200" alt="Uploaded by user">
```

But this will not displaying image on my webpage? :(
I got following error when I hit inspect element option in browser

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///H:/IVS-FEB%202016/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/IVS/uploads/share1.png

Comment: No its not working, Its still not displaying image

Answer (score 2):

Write a Java Servlet. See [**example tutorial**](https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-display-image-using-servlet).

Eg:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    ServletOutputStream oStream;
    String fileName = "your file";
    try (FileInputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName))) 
    {
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        oStream = response.getOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while ((len = iStream.read(buffer)) != -1) 
        { oStream.write(buffer, 0, len); }

    }

    oStream.flush();
    oStream.close();
}
```

Then in your HTML/JSP page use:

```
<img src="ImageServlet"/>
```

You can pass parameters if you have multiple images based on any condition and do your logic to choose in the Servlet class.